# Sample from tail of normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, simulation

I'm writing some simulations and I've found I need to oversample the tails of a normal distribution in order to get enough samples with a low value for a particular variable. Is there anything better than this?

```
from scipy.stats import norm, uniform
tail_high = .01
n_samples = 1000
tail_rvs = norm.ppf(uniform.rvs(0, tail_high, n_samples))
```

Comment: Ideally the best way would be to sample from a truncated normal distribution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution which is implemented in scipy.  I don't know if its current implementation is optimized for sampling from tails.  Another possibility is that you are 'doing it wrong' and that you actually want to sample from a less informative distribution (maybe like a cauchy distribution or a normal distribution with more variance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really need to sample from a normal distribution, you can probably DIY http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method or http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box–Muller_transform

There is an open issue for truncnorm as currently implemented in scipy
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2477. The original ticket gives links to several alternative implementations.