# Specifiying range for log-normal distribution in Python

Tags: python, numpy, distribution

I am generating a random log-normal distribution using the inbuilt function. Is it possible to specify a range for a given `mean` and `sigma`? For instance, I want a random distribution between `0` and `0.5` with `mean=0.2, sigma=0.5`?

```
import numpy as np 

r=np.random.lognormal(mean=0.2, sigma=0.5, size=(3,3))
print([r])
```

Comment: AFAIK, lognormal distribution does not have a bounded range of definition like normal distribution. You certainly need a truncated lognormal distribution but this one is not provided by Numpy. That being said, if the range is reasonable, I think you can repeat the operation to obtain a truncated lognormal distribution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting numpy.random.lognormal to a given range, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51995490/restricting-numpy-random-lognormal-to-a-given-range-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but you can generate more points and filter those that are outside your parameters. With the values you provided, however, there will be very few such points:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
z = np.random.lognormal(mean=0.2, sigma=0.5, size=10_000)

>>> np.sum(z < 0.5) / len(z)
0.0346
```

As a side note, please know that the parameters `mean` and `sigma` of `np.random.lognormal()` refer to the underlying normal distribution, not to the `mean` and `std` of the log-normal points:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
z = np.random.lognormal(mean=0.2, sigma=0.5, size=1000)
y = np.log(y)

>>> np.mean(z), np.std(z)
(1.3886515119063163, 0.7414709414626542)

>>> np.mean(y), np.std(y)
(0.2018986489272414, 0.5034218384643446)
```

All that said, if you really want what you asked for, you could do:

```py
shape = 3, 3
zmin, zmax = 0, 0.5

n = np.prod(shape)
zc = np.array([])
while True:
    z = np.random.lognormal(mean=0.2, sigma=0.5, size=n * 100)
    z = z[(zmin <= z) & (z < zmax)]
    zc = np.r_[zc, z]
    if len(zc) >= n:
        break
r = zc[:n].reshape(shape)

>>> r
array([[0.34078793, 0.45366409, 0.40183988],
       [0.43387773, 0.46387512, 0.30535007],
       [0.44248787, 0.32316698, 0.48600577]])
```

Note, however, that the loop above (which in this case is done on average just once), may run forever if your bounds specify an empty space.

**Edit**

For efficiency, we can use instead [scipy.stats.truncnorm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html). However, there seems to be an issue when `loc, scale != 0, 1`, so here we roll out our own adjustment:

```py
# convert X ~ N(0, 1) to Y ~ N(u, s):
# Y = X * s + u
# want Y in [a, b]:
# so X in [(a - u)/s, (b - u)/s]
#
# We want Z ~ logN(u, s) in [zmin, zmax]
# Z = exp(Y) and
# a, b = np.log((zmin, zmax))

def lognormal(a, b, loc=1, scale=1, size=1):
    a, b = np.log((a, b))
    ca, cb = (np.array((a, b)) - loc) / scale
    rv = truncnorm(a=ca, b=cb)
    z = np.exp(rv.rvs(size=size) * scale + loc)
    return z
```

Example:

```py
zmin, zmax = 0, 0.5
z = lognormal(zmin, zmax, 0.2, 0.5, 10_000)
```

Or, to capture the rather noisy warning from `np.log(0)`:

```py
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=RuntimeWarning, message='divide by zero encountered in log') 
    z = lognormal(zmin, zmax, 0.2, 0.5, 10_000)
```

Either way, we now have:

```py
np.min(z), np.max(z)
(0.10787873738453256, 0.4999993445360746)
```

And the same distribution than one would get with the above (`r`) with `shape = 10_000`:

```py
def lognormal_naive(a, b, loc=1, scale=1, size=1):
    zc = np.array([])
    while True:
        z = np.random.lognormal(mean=loc, sigma=scale, size=n * 100)
        z = z[(a <= z) & (z < b)]
        zc = np.r_[zc, z]
        if len(z) >= size:
            break
    return zc[:size]

r = lognormal_naive(zmin, zmax, 0.2, 0.5, 10_000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(7, 2))
ax[0].hist(z, bins=100)
ax[1].hist(r, bins=100);
```

[image]

However, the timing is much better:

```py
%timeit lognormal_naive(zmin, zmax, 0.2, 0.5, 10_000)
64.2 ms ± 60.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit lognormal(zmin, zmax, 0.2, 0.5, 10_000)
2.06 ms ± 3.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This approach is generally very inefficient if the array is relatively big (or/and the range small) as it regenerate all the value if only few value are outside the range. The probability of having such an event should very close to one for big arrays. The `n*100` mitigate the problem for this case but this generate 100x time more values than required in the worst case... In pathological cases it can be many orders of magnitude slower than actually required.

Comment: In fact, this is getting *exponentially slower* with the size in pathological cases. For example a 10x10 matrix with `zmin, zmax = 0, 0.35` takes several minutes while a basic (naive) code finding the values one by one takes 0.0005 second on my machine. This is >200_000 times slower!

Comment: Indeed, as noted in the answer. Clipping a log-normal distribution is simply not a good idea to start with. For degenerate cases, you'd probably build something ad-hoc to draw from the tail of the normal distribution and then take the log. See. e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28868550/758174).

Comment: See updated answer using `scipy.stats.truncnorm`.

Comment: Indeed, much better (especially in pathological cases). For the warning, I think it is better to use a zmin set to a very small value like 1e-15 so to avoid a `log(0)` instead of hiding the problem.